# PropertyAccessException when using Criteria API to query an entity with self-reference

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following entity:

```
package model.entity;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Folder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent")
    private Folder parent;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private Set<Folder> children;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="containerFolder")
    private Set<Project> projects;

    @Column
    private Integer orderIndex;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String name) {
        this.title = name;
    }

    public Folder getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Folder parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Set<Folder> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<Folder> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public Set<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(Set<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    public Integer getOrderIndex() {
        return orderIndex;
    }

    public void setOrderIndex(Integer orderIndex) {
        this.orderIndex = orderIndex;
    }



}
```

I use Criteria API to query to find all children of the parent.

```
Session session = (Session) JPA.em().getDelegate();
List rootFolderList = session.createCriteria(Folder.class).add(Restrictions.isNull("parent")).list();

if (rootFolderList.isEmpty()) {
    Folder root = new Folder();
    root.setTitle("root");
    JPA.em().persist(root);
    rootFolder = root;
} else
    rootFolder = (Folder) rootFolderList.get(0);


Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Folder.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("parent", rootFolder.getId()));
List<Folder> folders = criteria.list();
```

The first query which gets the root element is not a problem. It finds the root element and does not give an error. However, the second query throws an exception on the **list()** method.

```
[PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of model.entity.Folder.id]
```

For the exception, there are several solutions but they didn't work for me:

- Downgrading Hibernate version to 4.3.5 or lower. Didn't work.
- Keeping the latest Hibernate version but setting
  **hibernate.classloading.use_current_tccl_as_parent** to **false**. Didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first query which gets the root element is not a problem

I doubt that, since the query tries to find all the folders which don't have an ID (and all obviously have one: an entity can't exist without an ID). What it should actually do is find the entities which don't have a **parent**. That will give you the root folder(s).

Then you do

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("parent", rootFolder.getId()));
```

How could the parent, of type Folder, be equal to an rootFolder.getId(), of type Long?

What you want is

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("parent", rootFolder));
```

or

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("parent.id", rootFolder.getId()));
```

Comment: Thanks! Just got it right and came back to delete the question... only to see it is already answered. :)

Comment: Btw query to find parents was wrong too and I fixed it already. Folder which does not have a parent is root.